# How Do I Prevent Reload of UICollectionViewCells in cellForItemAt?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionViewController in which I contact an API to download images based on a set of coordinates. I call this code in the cellForItemAt function at which time it updates the cell's images in realtime with images from Flickr. This works fine.

However, when scrolling up or down, it recalls this code and updates the cells again, when I'd prefer that it look at the existing cells, identify if they have been filled, and simply not run this code.

I have tried implementing logic before the networking code that checks to see if the imageView.images already exist in a local struct I assign them to, but that doesn't seem to work correctly.

Is there a simple method to tell cellForItemAt "for cells where you already have images, don't look for more"?

Here is my current code:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        // Get images = using the URL
        FlickrClient.sharedInstance().getImagesFromFlickr(latitude: selectedPin.lat, longitude: selectedPin.lon, page: pageCount) { (pin, error) in

            if let pin = pin {
                let url = pin.images[indexPath.item].imageURL
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                performUIUpdatesOnMain {
                    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                }
            }
        }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Cells objects are reused once they scroll out of view, so `cellForItemAt` is only called when the collectionview needs a cell since it doesn't already have one. You can use a NSCache or SDWebImage to cache the images for you. Also, why do you get the image urls from Flickr each time instead of fetching the urls once?

Comment: This is for a class, and part of the rubric is that images are shown as they download. Thanks for the other suggestions.

Comment: That is still no reason to fetch the data from flickr each time a cell is dequeued; The list of images will only change when the selected pin is changed; You only need to call `getImagesFromFlickr` once per pin selection.  If you don't want to use a 3rd party framework like SDWebImage then use `NSCache`

Answer (score 0):

Use SDwebImage libray for loading images from url.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Call Something like this on cell for row :

```
let url = pin.images[indexPath.item].imageURL
cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```